# MySQL "SSL Connection Error System Library" when connecting to SQLyog

Tags: mysql, laragon, sqlyog

Previously I used XAMPP without any problems. But now I want to migrate to Laragon. I'm having trouble connecting SQL to SQLyog. I use windows 11.

`Error No. 2026 SSL error connection: system library`

```
2024-03-29T16:47:37.250449Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010097] [Server] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2024-03-29T16:47:37.250496Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2024-03-29T16:47:37.250521Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.30-winx64\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 13632
2024-03-29T16:47:37.278541Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-03-29T16:47:37.501288Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-03-29T16:47:37.836826Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013829] [Server] Missing data directory for ICU regular expressions: C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.30-winx64\lib\private\.
2024-03-29T16:47:37.841164Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-03-29T16:47:37.841753Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-03-29T16:47:37.899690Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2024-03-29T16:47:37.899788Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.30-winx64\bin\mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```